# Finding the distribution of a function of a normal random variable

Tags: self-study, distributions, normal-distribution

**Question:**  A particle's velocity $V$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$. The particle's energy is given by $W=m\frac{V^2}{2}$, where $m>0$ is a constant.

(a) What is $\text{E}[W]$ in terms of $m$ and $\sigma^2$?
(b) What is the PDF of $W$?

I'll post my best attempt below but I'm curious if there is an easier approach to (b). I'm trying to get better at this techniques for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks @DilipSarwate.  Unfortunately many in the world (including me) are not "steeped in statistical knowledge."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a)
$\begin{align}\text{E}[W]&=\text{E}\left[\frac{mV^2}{2}\right] \\
&=\frac{m}{2}\text{E}[V^2] \\
&=\frac{m}{2}\left(\text{Var}(V)+\text{E}[V]^2 \right) \\
&=\frac{m}{2}(\sigma^2 + 0) \\
&=\frac{m \sigma^2}{2}
\end{align}$

(b) To get the PDF for $W$, start with CDF.  The CDF is zero for $w<0$ so compute it for $w\ge 0$.

$\begin{align}F_W(w)&=P(W\le w) \\
&=P\left( \frac{mV^2}{2} \le w \right) \\
&=P\left( V^2 \le \frac{2w}{m} \right) \\
&=P\left( |V| \le \sqrt{\frac{2w}{m}} \right) \\
&=P\left( -\sqrt{\frac{2w}{m}} \le V \le \sqrt{\frac{2w}{m}} \right) \\
&=F_V \left( \sqrt{\frac{2w}{m}} \right) - F_V \left( -\sqrt{\frac{2w}{m}} \right)
\end{align}$

Now the CDF is done since $V\sim \text{Normal}(0,\sigma^2)$ so $F_V$ is known.

Now take the derivative with respect to $w$...
\begin{align} f_W(w) &= \frac{d}{dw}F_W(w) \\
&= f_V \left( \sqrt{\frac{2w}{m}} \right)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{w}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}} + f_V \left( -\sqrt{\frac{2w}{m}} \right)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{w}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2mw}}\left[ f_V \left( \sqrt{\frac{2w}{m}} \right) +f_V \left( -\sqrt{\frac{2w}{m}} \right) \right] \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2mw}}\left[ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}\text{e}^{-\frac{2w}{2m \sigma^2}}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}\text{e}^{-\frac{2w}{2m \sigma^2}}} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{mw \pi \sigma^2}}\text{e}^{-\dfrac{w}{m \sigma^2}} 
\end{align}

---

Update:  @DilipSarwate [(user profile)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/6633/dilip-sarwate) has kindly pointed out that $W$ follows a *scaled* [Chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution), specifically a scaled $\chi^2(1)$ pdf.

Comment: I can't figure out the MathJax error....will return with fresh eyes to attempt a fix.

Comment: I'll be interested to look at the proper coding of your equation if you can fix it. Not familiar with using 'align'. Will say you lack a couple of `}`'s to end `\sqrt`s. meanwhile, I see your PDF is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{mw \pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{2w}{2m \sigma^2}}.$

Comment: Thank you @DilipSarwate.  I will update this.  Based on your opening phrase, if you have concerns feel free to discuss them with me in chat.  My intent is not to undermine CV.SE and I'll gladly listen to your perspective.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, thank you for the correction.  I had typed that up without much sleep. You claim my answers (plural) have typos so I'll review my other answers too. Typos are accidents and not intentional.  Will look at references you posted to comments. Perhaps we should move to chat if you want to discuss this more. I don't think comments if the right place for this discussion.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, I've created [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84630/discussion-between-secretagentman-and-dilip-sarwate) so you can express your concerns.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial confirmation,** using simulation in R: Let $\sigma^2 = 4, \sigma=2, m = 10.$

```
set.seed(1017);  B = 10^6;  sg = 2;  m = 10
v = rnorm(B, 0, sg);  w = .5*m*v^2
mean(w);  m*sg^2/2
[1] 20.02141   # aprx energy = 20
[1] 20         # exact energy
hist(w, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="Histogram of Kinetic Energy")
curve((pi*m*x)^-.5/sg*exp(-x/(m*sg^2)), 0, 400, add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
   # note: curve function requires argument 'x'
```

[image]

**Everything seems OK,** methods and results (+1). Your expectation is within the margin of simulation error for the constants I used, and your density function seems a good match for
the histogram. I think kinetic energy has a gamma distribution with shape parameter 1/2. (Maybe see Wikipedia on 'gamma distribution'.)

**Possible alternative method for PDF.** You might find it easier to get the PDF of $W$ from the normal PDF of $V$ using the 'PDF method' (also called 'transformation' method)
shown in many elementary or intermediate probability texts. I think it's especially easy here because the transformation and  the Jacobian are simple.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I have been thinking about, here is what I have come up with:

Q:

What is the $\mathrm{pdf}$ of the random variable $Y$, $f_Y(y)$, given $y=U(x)$ and given the $\mathrm{pdf}$ of $X$, $f_X(x)$?

A:

$f_Y(y)=\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} y} F_X \left (U^{-1}(y)  \right )$

Where $F_X(x)$ is the $\mathrm{cdf}$ of $X$, and $U^{-1}(y)$ is the inverse function of $y=U(x)$.

---

Q:

What is $f_Y(y)$, given $y=x^n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma)$?

A:

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2\,n^2}}\,y^{-1+1/n}\,\mathrm{exp}\left ( -\frac{(y^{1/n}-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right ) \times
\left\{\begin{matrix}
2, & n~\mathrm{even}, & 0 < y < \infty\\ 
1, & n~\mathrm{odd}, & -\infty < y < \infty
\end{matrix}\right.$

Which agrees with your answer when $\omega\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: (+1), Interesting.  I hadn't considered that approach.  Thanks for sharing.